# Trigger sentence is heard but does not trigger behaviour

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

I have followed the tutorial from the [documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/software/choregraphe/tutos/create_application.html) to try out trigger sentences.

In Choregraphe I have a single "Animated Say" box. The "onStart" input of the box is connected to the "onStart" box on the left side of the box area and the "onStopped" output is connected to the "onStopped" box on the right side of the box area, exactly like in the tutorial. When I connect to NAO and press the "Run" button the robot moves and talks, as expected. I have set a trigger sentence for the behaviour. The project is also installed on the robot.

However when I say the trigger sentence I get no response. The sentence is "Why do you exist". The Dialog box in Choregraphe shows me that I am heard: "Human: Why do you exist (97.575%)" but the robot does not respond whatsoever. The robot does talk when I say sentences such as "Hi Nao" and "Who are you". It seems to me like the trigger sentence is not properly checked.

What can I do to make the robot execute my behaviour when I say a trigger sentence?

Comment: Do you have the [basic channel](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao-naoqi-2-1/nao-documentation/nao-user-guide/more-details-about-nao/understanding-autonomous-life#basic-channel) dialog running on NAO? This is needed for trigger sentences to be detected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Choregraphe behavior is an [Activity](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/software/choregraphe/objects/activity.html?highlight=activity) and that the autonomous life is on (this is the default when no other activity is running).

In short, the "nature" of the behavior should be "Interactive", and the robot should not be running any activity (make sure to stop your previous run of your activity).